# Keep oversized background image centered

Tags: css, html, parallax

I am building a single page site constructed of 4 divs, one on top of the other and each one with its own fixed background image. The images are much wider than the screen as I want to site to keep its look across a large range of screen sizes, however does anyone know how to truely center a background image. So in a small monitor they would be viewing the center of the image, and in a larger monitor they would see the same place of the image, just with more around it. Just like this site has

http://www.cantilever-chippy.co.uk/

When the window is resized the background image moves accordingly.

Many Thanks.

Comment: when you give your wrapper a static width, the position of the background-images is also static, because the width is on every resolution the same (960px).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you check the css from your link you see the solution:

```
#images #bg_1 {
  background-image: url(images/bg/1.jpg);
  background-position: 50% 0;
}
```

And the div:

```
<div class="bg_block" id="bg_1" style="height: 1200px; width: 1055px;"></div>
```

By JavaScript they change the width of #bg_1 on every resize.

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    $("#bg_1").css("width", $(window).width());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I should have mentioned above that I have tried all css ways of positioning an image and it always just puts them aligned top left, frustratingly!

Comment: Ok i see, they change the width of the div with every resize of the page. I edit my post.

Answer (score 9):

This should work

```
#bg{ 
   background-image:url(yourURL);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-attachment:fixed;
   background-position:center; 
}
```

The background-fixed property is for Firefox and Opera.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `background-position` CSS property.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

It can take an absolute offset in pixels (so if you know the size of your image and the size of the div you could calculate exactly where you want it to appear). Or, you can pass in a percentage.  It can also take a negative numbers so you can offset it off the screen in any direction.

For your case, though, you probably want the simple "center" value. Something like this should work:

```
/* This should center the background image in the div. */
div.background_image_block {  
  background-position: center center;
}
```